# Datagridview active row set is not selectable?

Tags: datagridview

```
Dim index As Integer = DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
       'Do events..
        row.Cells(1).Value = "Loading.."
        row.ReadOnly = True
Next
```

Sorry my English a little.
My gridview editing and deleting is enable. I want:
if Cell value is "Loading.." then this row is not select or delete by user.
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OnEvent: UserDeletingRow you can canceled it: Example.

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_UserDeletingRow(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowCancelEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.UserDeletingRow
        If (e.Row.Cells(1).Value = "loading") Then
            e.Cancel = True
        End If

End Sub
```